# minimal sufficient statistic for $U(\theta, \theta+c)$. $(\theta,c)$ unknown

Tags: self-study, uniform-distribution, sufficient-statistics

> Suppose $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ are $i.i.d$ from a distribution with p.d.f
> $$\delta_{(\theta,c)}(x)=\frac{1}{c}\mathbb{1}_{(x\in[\theta,\theta+c])},$$
> where $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}^+$ unknown.
>
> Find a minimal sufficient statistic for $(\theta,c)$.

From the range of $x_i$, i.e. $x_i\in[\theta,\theta+c]$, we can determine that $\theta\leq x_i$ and $\theta+c\geq x_i$, $\forall i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$. This implies $$\theta\leq x_{(1)}\text{ and }\theta+c\geq x_{(n)},$$ where $x_{(1)}=\underset{i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}}{\min}x_i$ and $x_{(n)}=\underset{i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}}{\max}x_i$.

The plots shows the area of $\theta\leq x_{(1)}\text{ and }\theta+c\geq x_{(n)}.$ It look like that $(x_{(1)},x_{(n)})$ is a minimal sufficient statistic for $(\theta,c)$ because $(x_{(1)},x_{(n)})$ uniquely determines the shape of the log-likelihood function. **Is this correct?**

[image: illustration]

Comment: Sufficient statistics are for the entire parameter vector, not for components of the parameter vector. Cfr the definition of sufficiency.

Comment: This shows the pair $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ is sufficient. To show it is minimal, you have to demonstrate that two different realisations of $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ lead to two different likelihood functions.

Comment: @Xi'an. Thanks. This is a good reminder. $t(x)=t(y)\iff l_x(\theta)= l_y(\theta)+const$ here $l$ is log-likelihood and $\theta$ is the parameter. I've updated my question. I still have a little bit confusion on how to actually step-by-step show that $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ is a minimal sufficient statistics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Nobody answers so I post this answer which I am not sure is correct)

We show $(Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)})$ is a sufficient complete statistic, which implies $(Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)})$ is minimal sufficient. We first give the p.d.f of $(Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)})$
$$f(y_1, y_n,\theta,c)=\frac{n(n-1)}{c^n}(y_n-y_1)^{n-1},\quad\forall \theta\leq y_1\leq y_n\leq \theta+c\text{ and } (\theta,c)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^+$$

Then, for any function $g(x_1,x_n)$ so that $\mathbb{E}_{\theta,c}\left[g(y_1,y_n)\right]=0,\forall (\theta,c)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^+$, we have $$0=\frac{n(n-1)}{c^n}\int_{\theta}^{\theta+c}\int_{\theta}^{y_n}g(y_1,y_n)(y_n-y_1)^{n-2} dy_1dy_n,\forall (\theta,c)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^+$$
The integral area of $(y_1, y_n)$ is a triangle with vertices $(\theta,\theta)$, $(\theta,\theta+c)$ and $(\theta+c,\theta+c)$. With varying $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ $c\in\mathbb{R}^+$, these triangles generate the Beral $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{B}=\{(x,z)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x\leq z\}$. Thus
$$0=\frac{n(n-1)}{c^n}\int_{A}g(y_1,y_n)(y_n-y_1)^{n-2} d(y_1,y_n),\text{ for any Borel set }A\subset\mathcal{B}.$$
This means $$g(y_1,y_n)(y_n-y_1)^{n-2}\equiv0,a.e.\iff g\equiv 0,a.e.$$
Thus we conclude $(Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)})$ is a complete statistic for $(\theta,c).$

Since $(Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)})$ is sufficient by factorization theorem, we conclude $(Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)})$ is minimal sufficient.

Comment: (+1) This seems correct to me. The [fact that complete+sufficient implies minimal sufficient](http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~shao/stat609/stat609-24.pdf) is not so well-known.